# has_and_belongs_to_many association confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So I have an application that has a blog model,and a user model.

Now users can subscribe to many different blogs, and users can also create many of their own blogs.

What would the association look like?

Right now my models look like the following:

Blog.rb:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :posts

end
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :blogs     

  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :password, on: :create         

end
```

the user table has a blog_id:integer field, and the blog has a user_id:integer field.

Is this right?

And how would the commands work? I.E:

```
u = User.last
b = u.blogs.build(title: "bla")
b.user (shows the owner of the blog)
b.users (shows the users that have subscribed to the blog)
```

Ultimately, I'd like to allow users to subscribe to other peoples blogs, and create their own.

Comment: You've got a mix of Rails 4 style and earlier versions here. `validates :password, presence: true, on: :create` is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to add a third model 'Subscriptions'. Then you are going to want to use the 'has_many_through:' association. Please read this section of the rails guides for a detailed example. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association.

After you create the associations you are going to want to do something along these lines: 
1) make sure you nest the 'subscriptions' routes underneath the blog route properly.

```
resources :blogs, only: [] do
    resources :subscriptions, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

2) Create a _subscription.html.erb partial in app/views/subscriptions

3) Render the partial in blogs#show

```
<%= render partial: 'subscriptions/_subscription, locals: {blog: @blog}
```

4) Add the ability to add (create) a subscription in the partial: (this is only to add subscription, you will want to also add ability to remove)

```
 <%= link_to [blog, Subscription.new], class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post do %>
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"> </i>&nbsp; Subscribe
 <% end %>
```

5) Add 'create method' to subscriptions_controller.rb

```
   def create
     @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
     subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build(blog: @blog)

     if subscription.save
       # Add code
     else
       # Add code
     end
   end
```

This should be enough direction to get you to the finish line. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! So I've setup the HMT association by creating a subscription model that belongs to users and blogs. And obviously, the user has_many :subscriptions, and has_many :blogs, through: :subscriptions and the same process for the blog. How do I actually allow users to subscribe to a blog?

Comment: I updated my answer for you. I didn't go into great detail.. But it should give you the idea.

Comment: Okay thanks as much detail as possible would be great when you get a chance, but this looks awesome. Will give it a shot and circle back!

Comment: getting undefined method subscriptions_path ? when visiting blogs/new

Comment: Are you willing to add the routes when you get a moment? Cheers

Comment: I will get back to you in a little bit!

Comment: Ok so what do you see for blog when you run rake routes..
we want to see something like:

`blog_subscriptions POST     /blogs/:blog_id/subscriptions(.:format)        subscriptins#create`